# js error: You may need an appropriate loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I did is just import a npm package

```
import TimePicker from 'simple-timepicker-react'

render () {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <TimePicker />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

and I got this error in my terminal when starting my webapp.

```
./node_modules/simple-timepicker-react/src/SimpleTimePicker.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (194:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
|     return (
|       <div id="datetime-selector" style={{ width: containerWidth }}>
|         <div className="placeholderInput-wrap">
|           <input
```

Isn't that is a javascript file? What kind of loader I need? I don't get the meaning of the error.

Comment: A JSX loader. You can use TypeScript or Babel to transpile JSX ahead of time or use either of their respective Webpack loaders to do so only the fly. Plenty of other options as well of course.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I have react installed can't use jsx? I'm confused.

Comment: React is a framework that emphasizes JSX but it doesn't implememt or ship with a JSX compiler. You need to use a third-party tool.

Comment: JSX is not valid javascript on its own, it must be transformed to actual javascript. How you do so will depend on your bundler, but it will most likely involve something like this:
https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-react-jsx/

Comment: Also... the code as posted doesn't seem to define a component... and even with the appropriate loader, generally I believe you need to have imported `React` into scope to use JSX in a module...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React uses a tag syntax extension to JavaScript called [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html).
In order to transform that syntax into valid JS you need to use some tools.
One possible way to do so is using [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) and [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to load, transform and bundle your scripts.

Using the [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) with a [preset for react](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/) you can import and work with JSX scripts.

You can check the [webpack-4](/questions/tagged/webpack-4) config in this [Webpack Demo](https://github.com/carloluis/webpack-demo) project using React.

---

Configure the babel loader in *webpack.config.js* and *.babelrc* files:

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
        ]
    }
    // ...
};
```

*.babelrc*

```
{
    "presets": ["babel-preset-env", "babel-preset-react"]
}
```

**DevDependencies**: `babel-core`, `babel-loader`, `babel-preset-env`, `babel-preset-react`, `webpack`, `webpack-cli`